# RAY - RLLIB - Failing to train DQN using offline sample batch - episode_len_mean: .nan value

Tags: offline, reinforcement-learning, ray

RAY - RLLIB library - estimate a DQN model using offline batch data. Model fails to learn. episode_len_mean: .nan For CartPole example as well as personal-domain-specific dataset

Ubuntu
Ray library - RLIB
DQN
Offline
environment:-  tried with Cartpole-v0 as well as with custom environment example.

episode_len_mean: .nan
episode_reward_max: .nan
episode_reward_mean: .nan
episode_reward_min: .nan
episodes_this_iter: 0
episodes_total: 0

## Generate data using PG

```
rllib train --run=PG --env=CartPole-v0 --config='{"output": "/tmp/cartpole-out", "output_max_file_size": 5000000}' --stop='{"timesteps_total": 100000}'
```

## Train model on offline data

```
rllib train --run=DQN --env=CartPole-v0 --config='{"input": "/tmp/cartpole-out","input_evaluation": ["is", "wis"],"soft_q": true, "softmax_temp": 1.0}'
```

Expected :-
episode_len_mean: numerical values
episode_reward_max: numerical values
episode_reward_mean: numerical values
episode_reward_min: numerical values

Actual Results (No improvement observed in tensorboard as well) :-
episode_len_mean: .nan
episode_reward_max: .nan
episode_reward_mean: .nan
episode_reward_min: .nan

Comment: Clarification: environment has numpy 1.15.4 version and I get this error after 1st iteration and then values have "nan"s

Comment: (pid=11785) /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:2957: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
(pid=11785)   out=out, **kwargs)
(pid=11785) /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:80: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
(pid=11785)   ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)

Comment: The "Mean of empty slice." warning is probably the issue (which could explain why you're seeing `nan`. Does anything have length 0? E.g., are there some rollouts that terminate immediately?

Comment: With cart pole example I am not sure. Just ran these codes as in Ray offline dataset documentation page.   However, when have tried this on another offline dataset (webpage funnel booking behavior) I made sure to exclude rollouts with length 1 (i.e. that terminate immediately).  I get same warning messages in both cases. One of your team members suggested that this is expected when training offline. And was guided to look at ImportanceSampling/Weighted Importance sampling or Mean q values. I shared those charts in RAY-Dev google group. Need help there. I don't see converging patterns

Answer (score 0):

I had more or less the same problem and it was linked to the fact that the episode was never finishing because I didn't properly set the "done" value in the step function. Until an episode is "done", Ray doesn't calculate the metrics. In my case I had to specify a counter in the environment **init** function called self.count_steps and incremented on each step.

```
 def step(self, action):
    # Changes the yaw angles
    self.cur_yaws = action
    self.farm.calculate_wake(yaw_angles=action)
    # power output
    power = self.farm.get_farm_power()
    reward = (power-self.best_power)/self.best_power

    #if power > self.best_power:
    #    self.best_power = power

    self.count_steps +=1

    if self.count_steps > 50:
        done = True
    else:
        done = False

    return self.cur_yaws, reward, done, {}
```